# Api Gateway : How to modify end point URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How can we modify the endpoint URL of a method in API Gateway? I don't see any option anywhere.
[image]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't setup** custom domains for individual resources in your API. You can only setup [custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) for the entire api at once.

If you require different resources with different main domains, you need to create a new rest API for each.